# onmouseover event only works after second mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing some code that resizes a div when you hover over it, as well as some surrounding elements. It works perfectly, except that it will never fire the first time I mouse over one of the divs. If I mouse over each div one time first, from that point on it does exactly what I was hoping for. But I can't figure out why it needs 2 mouse overs.

**HTML**

```
<div id="comic_009" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_009', '#comic_008', '#comic_007')"></div>
<div id="comic_008" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_008', '#comic_009', '#comic_007')"></div>
<div id="comic_007" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_007', '#comic_008', '#comic_009')"></div>
<br class="clear"><br><br>
<div id="comic_006" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_006', '#comic_005', '#comic_004')"></div>
<div id="comic_005" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_005', '#comic_006', '#comic_004')"></div>
<div id="comic_004" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_004', '#comic_005', '#comic_006')"></div>
<br class="clear"><br><br>
<div id="comic_003" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_003', '#comic_002', '#comic_001')"></div>
<div id="comic_002" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_002', '#comic_003', '#comic_001')"></div>
<div id="comic_001" class="comic" onmouseover="resize('#comic_001', '#comic_002', '#comic_003')"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function resize(main, resized1, resized2){
            $(main).hover(
                function(){
                    $(main).css('width', '500px');
                    $(main).css('height', '400px');
                    $(main).css('margin-left', '10px');
                    $(resized1).css('width', '205px');
                    $(resized1).css('margin-left', '10px');
                    $(resized2).css('width', '205px');
                    $(resized2).css('margin-left', '10px');
                    $("#footer").css('margin-top', '300px');
                },
                function(){
                    $(main).css('width', '250px');
                    $(main).css('height', '200px');
                    $(main).css('margin-left', '50px');
                    $(resized1).css('width', '250px');
                    $(resized1).css('margin-left', '50px');
                    $(resized2).css('width', '250px');
                    $(resized2).css('margin-left', '50px');
                    $("#footer").css('margin-top', '0px');
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resize()` only *sets* the hover action the first time it is called; it doesn't actually *do* that action.

You should set the hover action for each of your images once before the first time the user interacts with the page. You could do this by calling each of the permutations of `resize(...)` above.  But it would be better to do this using classes, rather than ids.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYgyR/2/) for what I'm talking about with classes.

Comment: Ok I get it! That makes sense. And it will be easy to fix. 

Why would it be better to use classes than IDs? In this instance I have rows with 3 images in each row. When I hover over one image I want that one to expand while simultaneously shrinking the other two images in that row. If I tried to reuse classes I would end up with elements changing size that I don't want. Is there a benefit to using individual classes for each element as opposed to IDs?

Comment: The reason is that you could simplify your code a lot.  For example, have a `size_shifting` class, then classes like `group_1`, `group_2`, etc. Each time the user mouses over an item with the `size_shifting` class, shrink all other items in the same `group_x` class. You could set this up with one call to a single function, rather than lots of calls with lots of parameters to keep straight.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. And I definitely see how it would work and be cleaner. But I don't know what the code would be to shrink some elements from a class but enlarge another one from the same class. I was able to pretty quickly solve my mouseover problem though thanks to you. It's working perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I added a fiddle demonstrating what I mean by using classes; you can streamline this code tremendously, without having a zillion `onmouseover` calls or having to list all the affected ids repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're awesome! I can pretty much understand what you're doing with that fiddle, but there is some javascript in there I've never worked with before so I'm going to need to work my way through the pieces. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the fiddle with some comments to explain what I'm doing. Feel free to start a chat if you have additional questions.